# Получение типа данных переменной в Java

Tags: java, типы-данных

Как проверить тип переменной в Java?

Например, дана переменная `i`, и после вычислений и приведения типов я хочу узнать, к какому типу данных эта переменная в итоге была приведена.

Answer (score 2):

При объявлении вы задаёте тип переменной и этот тип остаётся неизменным в течение выполнения программы.

Например так:

```
int x = 10;
```

Однако вы можете сделать так:

```
double y = x;
```

То есть присвоить переменной **y** значение переменной **x** с приведением типа из *int* в тип *double*.

Но переменная **x** как была типа *int*, так и остаётся.

Comment: это я знаю, меня интересует оператор который будет возвращать значение "int" либо "float" , "double" и прочее